# Why is my CSS selector "body div span a" matching "<body><div><span><span><a>"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I thought the following selector would only match **example b**. Can someone explain to me a little more about how CSS paths work?

```css
body div span a{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div><span><span><a href="#">example a</a></span></span></div>
    <div><span><a href="#">example b</a></span></div>
    <span><div><span><a href="#">example c</a></span></div></span>
</body>
```

A visual example or a more elaborated tree/paths with "this will be affected", "this won't" would be extremely helpful to me. A link to a good guide could also be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for more information.

To simplify your example, a selector `div a { }` will match any `<a>` tag which *descends* from a `<div>` tag, regardless of how many levels of ancestry separate the two tags.

That is, `div a { }` will match any of the following:

```
<div> <a>...</a> </div>

<div> <h2> <a>...</a> </h2> </div>

<div> <h2> <span> <a>...</a> </span> </h2> </div>
```

If you want to match an `<a>` contained directly within a `<div>` with no other tags separating them, you need to use `div > a`, which matches only `<a>` tags that are *direct descendants* of a `<div>` tag.

Comment: And all of the examples are a's within span's within div's, so they all match.

Comment: and with a 3 path, no matter how much stuff is between each one, it would work? example: `a b c` x>e>A>x>o>o>B>y>e>C would work?

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess assuming that you're describing a nesting of tags with `x>e>A>x>...`, then yes. In terms of pattern matching, `a b c` would be like matching `*a*b*c`. Any number of tags containing an `<a>`, with a `<b>` nested within it at some arbitrary depth, with a `<c>` nested in that at some arbitrary depth. `a > b > c`, on the other hand, would be like matching `*a b c`.

Answer (score 3):

The way you're thinking uses the `>` symbol in CSS, which only gets the immediate children. For example, `body > div > span > a` would behave how you're expecting.

Otherwise, ANY child that matches the selector will be selected. So `div a` will select any `a` element under the `div`, no matter how any levels deep it's located.

Comment: and with a 3 path, no matter how much stuff is between each one, it would work? example: a b c x>e>A>x>o>o>B>y>e>C would work?

Comment: Assuming your second part was HTML and `a b c` are the CSS selectors, yeah, you would select C. The best advice though is simply do some experimenting if you're not sure. It'll all make sense soon enough.

Comment: I upvoted all answers because you all helped me with something. Is that bad? could I get banned if a moderator finds out?